# git on samba shares

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, git-for-windows

I have a folder of files exported via samba from a raspian-based system on a raspberry pi.  From windows, I did my git init on this folder mapped as drive T:.  Everything works fine there.

Now, I have an Ubuntu system that is mounting that samba share and I want to do development there too.  However, when I try to use git, it seems to be locked into the windows file structure:

```
$ git status
fatal: Could not chdir to 'T:/': No such file or directory
```

Is what I'm doing possible with git?  If I do the original git init on a Linux system, will Windows have problems?

The reo-local config file looks like this:

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    worktree = T:/
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
```

I don't have a .gitmodules file.

Comment: You should be able to answer your last question yourself.

Comment: What is the repo-local git config?

Comment: Do you have a `.gitmodules` file?